# Filtering records in one data frame based on another by matching multiple criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following two data frames, `dat1` and `dat2`:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- tribble(
  ~"subj", ~"drive", ~"measure",
  "A", 1, 1,
  "A", 1, 2,
  "A", 1, 3,
  "A", 1, 4,
  "A", 1, 5,
  "A", 2, 1,
  "A", 2, 2,
  "A", 2, 3,
  "A", 2, 4,
  "A", 2, 5,
  "B", 1, 1,
  "B", 1, 2,
  "B", 1, 3,
  "B", 1, 4,
  "B", 1, 5,
  "B", 2, 1,
  "B", 2, 2,
  "B", 2, 3,
  "B", 2, 4,
  "B", 2, 5,
)

dat2 <- tribble(
  ~"subj", ~"drive", ~"measure",
  "A", 1, 3,
  "B", 2, 4
)
```

And I am trying to filter the records in `dat1` based on the following conditions:

- `subj` and `drive` columns of `dat1` should match the `subj` and `drive` columns of `dat2`, and
- `measure` values in `dat1` should fall within a range of the `measure` values in `dat2`.

For this example, say the range is one unit apart. So, my result data frame will look like the following:

```
result <- tribble(
  ~"subj", ~"drive", ~"measure",
  "A", 1, 2,
  "A", 1, 3,
  "A", 1, 4,
  "B", 2, 3,
  "B", 2, 4,
  "B", 2, 5
)
```

I am aware of `dplyr::semi_join()` but it doesn't let me filter based on a range. Any ideas how I can solve this problem? `Tidyverse` based solutions will be great!

Comment: Are you saying that the results *have* to be one unit apart from the values in `dat2`, or should they just *fall within* the [-1, +1] range? If the former, you should reformulate your question. If the latter, the result should also contain `"A", 1, 3` and `"B", 2, 4`, correct?

Comment: @Brunox13, thanks! I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to first do an `inner_join` and then use `between`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(dat1, dat2, by = c('subj', 'drive')) %>% 
    group_by(subj, drive) %>% 
    filter(between(measure.x, first(measure.y)-1, first(measure.y) + 1)) %>% 
    select(measure = measure.x)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   subj, drive [2]
#  subj  drive measure
#  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A         1       2
#2 A         1       3
#3 A         1       4
#4 B         2       3
#5 B         2       4
#6 B         2       5
```

---

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[setDT(dat2), .SD[between(measure, i.measure -1,
          i.measure + 1)], on = .(subj, drive), by = .EACHI]
#    subj drive measure
#1:    A     1       2
#2:    A     1       3
#3:    A     1       4
#4:    B     2       3
#5:    B     2       4
#6:    B     2       5
```

Comment: I edited the question slightly based on the mistake pointed out by Brunox13. You may want to update your answer to match the new result data frame in my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashirwad  Thank you.  Updated the post

Answer (score 3):

Edited to use native sqldf string substitution as mentioned by GG's comment instead of sprintf.

```
library(sqldf)

check_range <- 1

fn$sqldf('
select  one.*
from    dat1 one
        join dat2 two
          on  one.subj = two.subj
              and one.drive = two.drive
              and one.measure - two.measure between -`check_range` and `check_range`
')
#   subj drive measure
# 1    A     1       2
# 2    A     1       3
# 3    A     1       4
# 4    B     2       3
# 5    B     2       4
# 6    B     2       5
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution which uses a *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
range <- 1
idx <- setDT(dat1)[
  setDT(dat2)[, .(subj, drive, lower = measure - range, upper = measure + range)], 
  on = .(subj, drive, measure >= lower, measure <= upper), which = TRUE]
dat1[idx]
```

> ```
>    subj drive measure
> 1:    A     1       2
> 2:    A     1       3
> 3:    A     1       4
> 4:    B     2       3
> 5:    B     2       4
> 6:    B     2       5
> ```